# Cannot run Angular 4 components on my laptop but works fine on online IDE

Tags: angular, typescript, components, webstorm

I created a new project and added new component inside but once I run it it doesn't work at all. I mean it doesn't link with the app component file, but I've tried creating a component using stackblitz and it works perfectly!

Here is my app structure

[image: structure]

And this is all the codes you may need to look at

#### app.component.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
     title = 'app';
     }
```

#### app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FirstComponent } from './first/first.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
FirstComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

#### app.component.html

```
<h1>Welcome.</h1>
<hr>
<app-first></app-first>
```

Then my component name is `first.component`

#### first.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-first',
templateUrl: './first.component.html'
})

export class FirstComponent {
}
```

#### first.component.html

```
<h2>Hi</h2>
<p>helllooooooooo</p>
```

I did the same thing inside stackblitz and its working totally fine, when I run it on WebStorm on my laptop it doesn't work, only app component html works without linking the app first html.

I'm running

```
Windows 10 win32 x64 
Angular cli version 1.4.9
node: 8.8.1
npm 5.4.2
```

If I'm doing anything wrong advise me. If you need any more resources just ask for it.

Comment: Looks all fine. Do you have any errors in the console? Check if your first.component.html has the correct name..

Comment: Thanks for your help but  how do i check that?

Comment: And as soon as i reach home i will see the console for errors

Comment: F12 on your browser. If there's any error post here.

Comment: No there is no errors, console is empty, i tried refreshing it, nothing came which means that my code is right, i noticed that in the elements section ( the first section when i press f12 before console) that app-first is identified as a normal element but it doesn't link with my other html file which is first.component.html, do you have any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: give parent path in templateUrl and try like this templateUrl: './first/first.component.html'

Comment: I solved the issue several days ago, thank you so much for your interest, i just didnt put the code ng serve everytime so when i close the terminal it didnt work, i had to write ng serve again, so, its a stupid mistake but it happens, anyway thank you.